# CentOS 7 Gnome excessive window title bars

Tags: virtualbox, taskbar, gnome, centos-7

I am running virtual machines hosted in CentOS 7 with VM VirtualBox. Gnome has an Apple-esque top bar that contains some menu items, followed by application specific items. Though in general no programs integrate with this interface and have, when maximised, their own title bar, and under than their own menu bar.

At the foot of the screen is the Windows-style taskbar. When running virtual machines evidently every window maximised inside it has its own title bar, menu and potentially taskbar. The loss of screen real-estate is a bit ridiculous and could be helped should applications in Gnome try to work with its title bar.

Can applications be instructed to better use the Gnome title bar? Can the bar be integrated with the taskbar in a Windows style? I know I can run the VM in fullscreen, but then I lose access to the host. Are there any other solutions people have?

Answer (score 1):

> Though in general no programs integrate with this interface and have, when maximised, their own title bar, and under than their own menu bar.

The integration points have actually been removed in current GNOME releases. The feature to hide the maximized window's titlebar has been gone for years; the ability to add app menu items went away with the latest release (it wasn't even close to an Apple-style menu in usefulness).

> At the foot of the screen is the Windows-style taskbar. [...] Can the bar be integrated with the taskbar in a Windows style?

The taskbar is added by an extension, usually as part of "GNOME Classic" or "Flashback" mode. It's not part of the standard GNOME 3 interface. If you're sure you have *not* selected the Classic mode at the login screen, use `gnome-tweaks` to disable the extension.

> The loss of screen real-estate is a bit ridiculous and could be helped should applications in Gnome try to work with its title bar.

Since the system bar integration has been removed, there's nothing you can do – short of rewriting the programs themselves (if they're GTK-based) to use the other recommended method of merging the title and menu bars into a single "header bar" like web browsers do:

[image]

> I know I can run the VM in fullscreen, but then I lose access to the host.

You can always press <kbd>RCtrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to minimize the VM's window and return to the host.

Comment: A good yet frustrating response. Linux developments seem to be plagued by half finished and part-thought-out solutions that end up being seized into place for lack of willpower to do what is necessary.